# How to use regexp in Elisp to match ',' in the line but not inside quotation mark

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

How could I write a regexp to match `,` in the line but not inside `""`?

For example:

```
`uvm_info("body", $sformatf("Value: a = %d, b = %d, c = %d", a, b, c), UVM_MEDIUM)
```

Hope to match those with `^` under it:

```
`uvm_info("body", $sformatf("Value: a = %d, b = %d, c = %d", a, b, c), UVM_MEDIUM)
                ^                                          ^  ^  ^   ^
```

Comment: When I first saw your question I though; easy peas. I was wrong lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function doesn't use a regular expression but rather parses a region of the buffer as sexps and returns a list of buffer positions of all commas excluding those within strings, or `nil` if there are no such commas.

```
(defun find-commas (start end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (let (matches)
      (while (< (point) end)
        (cond ((= (char-after) ?,)
               (push (point) matches)
               (forward-char))
              ((looking-at "[]\\[{}()]")
               (forward-char))
              (t
               (forward-sexp))))
      (nreverse matches))))
```

It works for the example you show, but might need tweaking for other examples or languages. If your example is in a buffer by itself, calling

```
(find-commas (point-min) (point-max))
```

returns

```
(17 60 63 66 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"[^"]+"|(,)
```

the **,** in capture group 1

Comment: Hi @wailid, your answer doesn't look like a Elisp regexp. I converted it as `"\\"[^"]+\\"\\|\\(,\\)"` and tried it in re-builder. It doesn't match anything.

Comment: I think that should convert as `"\"[^\"]+\"\\|\\(,\\)"` for "read" syntax, or `""[^"]+"\|\(,\)"` for "string" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that font-lock first fontifies comments and strings, then applies your font-lock keywords.

The standard solution is to replace your regexp with a function that search for the regexp, and skips any occurrences in comments and strings.

The following is from my package [lisp-extra-font-lock](https://github.com/Lindydancer/lisp-extra-font-lock) (a package that highlights variables bound by `let`, quoted expressions etc.) It search for quotes and backquotes, but the principle is the same:

```
(defun lisp-extra-font-lock-is-in-comment-or-string ()
  "Return non-nil if point is in comment or string.

This assumes that Font Lock is active and has fontified comments
and strings."
  (let ((props (text-properties-at (point)))
        (faces '()))
    (while props
      (let ((pr (pop props))
            (value (pop props)))
        (if (eq pr 'face)
            (setq faces value))))
    (unless (listp faces)
      (setq faces (list faces)))
    (or (memq 'font-lock-comment-face faces)
        (memq 'font-lock-string-face faces)
        (memq 'font-lock-doc-face faces))))


(defun lisp-extra-font-lock-match-quote-and-backquote (limit)
  "Search for quote and backquote in in code.
Set match data 1 if character matched is backquote."
  (let (res)
    (while (progn (setq res (re-search-forward "\\(?:\\(`\\)\\|'\\)" limit t))
                  (and res
                       (or
                        (lisp-extra-font-lock-is-in-comment-or-string)
                        ;; Don't match ?' and ?`.
                        (eq (char-before (match-beginning 0)) ??)))))
    res))
```

The font-lock keyword is as follows:

```
(;; Quote and backquote.
 ;;
 ;; Matcher: Set match-data 1 if backquote.
 lisp-extra-font-lock-match-quote-and-backquote
 (1 lisp-extra-font-lock-backquote-face nil t)
 ;; ...)
```

Comment: After re-reading your question I realised that it had nothing to do with font-lock... Anyway, if you would like to do this in a non font-lock context, I would recommend using other tools than regexp:s, e.g. `parse-partial-sexp`.